# How can I change 'long' to 'int' without changing 'long long' using perl/awk/etc

Tags: c++, perl, scripting, 32bit-64bit, editing

I want to change all the `long`s to `int`s (in preparation for 64 bit code).  I have a perl line that does:

```
s/(\s*long\s+)(?!long)/ int /g
```

which comes close.  It changes `long` to `int` and `long long` to `long int`.

Any editing method is good as long as it can be scripted or operate on multiple files.

```
*Sample:  input              desired output*
   long abd;                   int abd;
int longname;               int longname;
int reallylongname;         int reallylongname;
float reallylong longname;  float reallylong longname;
double namelong             double namelong
long abc long               int abc int
long long abc               long long abc
long    long hhhh           long    long hhhh
long long hhhh              long long hhhh
long abd( long kjhh         int abd( int kjhh
```

Comment: "long abc;" should become "int abc;".  "long long abc(long a)" should become "long long abc(int a)".  Extra points for preserving white-space, ignoring comments or doing it in a one-liner.

Comment: How about three passes: 1) convert all `long long` to something else, 2) convert `long int`, 3) convert something else back to `long long`. While you're at it, make typedefs for your basic types if you have to change them again in the future.

Comment: A bit brute force but very effective.  I like the simplicity of it.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, No need for multiple passes: 1) Convert a series of `long` to itself or to `int` depending on its length. See my answer.

Comment: @ikegani: Yeah, I'm sure it can be done better, I was just shooting from the hip. Your answer gives me a headache, but it has my +1 :-)

Comment: @Kerrek SB, You should see my update. That one even gives *me* a headache! But it works without /e :)

Answer (score 4):

The following would be ideal if variable width lookbehinds were supported:

```
s/
   (?<! \b long \s+)
   \b long \b
   (?! \s+ long \b)
/int/xg
```

That leaves you with the messier:

```
s/
   \b ( (?: long \s+ )* ) long \b
/
   length($1) ? $1."long" : "int"
/xeg
```

**Update**: This works as well:

```
s/
   (?<! \b long )
   (?<! \s ) \s* \K
   \b long \b
   (?! \s+ long \b)
/int/xg
```

**Update**: Tested using:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;

sub fix {
   my ($s) = @_;
   $s =~ s/
      \b ( (?: long \s+ )* ) long \b
   /
      length($1) ? $1."long" : "int"
   /xeg;
   return $s;
}

my @tests = (
   [ '   long abd;',                '   int abd;'                ],
   [ 'int longname;',               'int longname;'              ],
   [ 'int reallylongname;',         'int reallylongname;'        ],
   [ 'float reallylong longname;',  'float reallylong longname;' ],
   [ 'double namelong',             'double namelong'            ],
   [ 'long abc long',               'int abc int'                ],
   [ 'long long abc',               'long long abc'              ],
   [ 'long    long hhhh',           'long    long hhhh'          ],
   [ 'long long hhhh',              'long long hhhh'             ],
   [ 'long abd( long kjhh',         'int abd( int kjhh'          ],
);

plan tests => 0+@tests;

for (@tests) {
   my ($i,$e) = @$_;
   my $g = fix($i);
   is($g, $e, $i);
}

1;
```

Comment: Just curious: Why don’t you use curlies when you have multiline thingies?

Comment: @tchrist, I don't see what one has to do with the other. I imagine you think it makes it more readable, but its the indenting that shows the end of the expression, not the specific character at that location. If anything, I only see curlies making any difference when the substitution is embedded in a single line.

Comment: I don’t know whether it makes it more readable or not; I just know I can’t make `vi` bounce on the boundaries with the `%` key the way I can with braces or any other matching bracket. I have all kinds of keystroke macros set up to do way cool things with braces, so they’re easier to use (e.g. one keystroke is bound to open brace, CR, close brace, open line above and indent—still in insert.)  I only ever use nonbracketing delimiters when there aren’t newlines involved, or when I’m using Perl’s “hasta” operator in its `<<`LA_VISTA construct, which doesn’t apply to the pick-your-quotes scenarios.

Comment: @tchrist, Those are not issues for me and I wasn't aware of them.

Comment: @tchrist: Did you coin the term "hasta operator"? After googling a little I can only find SO posts by you mentioning it and I still don't know what you mean by it.

Comment: ... I'm a bit unclear about the complexity of this, but what does this do better than my solution?

Comment: @musiKk Yes, I coined it.  It means "till" in Spanish.  It makes a heckuva lot more sense than calling it a heredoc operator.

Comment: @tchrist: Well, but when you say heredoc people know what it means and can search for it. A lot of terms are like this. And I don't know Spanish. Just saying...

Comment: @musiKk: I will bet you that about 10,000 times more North American English speakers know what *hasta* means compared with those who have ever heard of a *heredoc*. Anybody who hasn’t heard *hasta la vista* has no ears.  See Arnold.

Comment: I like the solution but I didn't make clear that I wanted to leave 'long long' as-is.  The first thing I tried was the variable length look-behind, was surprised to see it wasn't supported.

Comment: @Pete, it’s really frustrating not having them. I believe the only languages that fully support variable‐length lookbehind are .ɴᴇᴛ, Matthew Barnett’s `regex` module for Python, and the Perl 6 spec. ᴘᴄʀᴇ supports alternation of fixed‐width alternatives in its lookbehinds, but those you can always craft yourself if you must, *e.g.* $left_edge = qr{ (?<= \A ) | (?<= \s ) }x`. Actually figuring how to rewrite it for truly variable‐width pieces is a real pain; there are a couple different techniques that you sometimes see as workarounds, but most people just give up.

Comment: Hm, it looks like Rakudo’s Perl6 regexes are a long ways from the spec still. It can do `$string ~~ s:g/ long  <!before \s+ long > /WRONG/` for a negated lookahead, but it can’t do `<!after long \s+ >`. It also can’t word boundaries using `<|w>`.

Comment: @dascandy, I don't know that one is better than the other. Repeated s/// are very hard to verify as being correct, though, whereas it's very easy to see what patterns the 2nd snippet of mine matches, a series of `long`. (I don't recommend using the third snippet.)

Comment: @Pete, Removed a useless lookahead in my solution.

Comment: @Pete, My code should leave long long as is (and I thought you did make that clear). Are you saying it doesn't? Oh I see, I use `$2` without populating it. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/\blong  *int\b/int/g' -e 's/\blong\b/int/g' -e 's/\bint\(  *\)int\b/long\1long/g'
```

Just replace those back that are now wrong?

edits: added white space conservation, added Kerrek SB's fix

Comment: `char belong(int interrupt) { return '!'; }`

Comment: You don't get longerrupts on your computers? :-)

Comment: Only after the intern pulled an all-nighter updating our codez :-)

Comment: @Kerrek SB it happened to me before - wanted to substitute template parameter Y by void. Forgot both cap sensitivity and word boundaries, so I got tvoidpenames in my code :-)

Comment: Hehe - yeah, those replacements are best done interactively for a couple of cases before you hit that "apply to entire disk" button!

Comment: @Kerrek SB, Those replacements are best done after a *backup* (incl one created by commiting). Not only does this allow you to undo errors, it allows you to do a diff to see exactly what you changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to do four passes, convert `long int` to `long$int`, convert `long` to `int`, then `int int` to `long long`, and `long$int` back to `long int`.

Comment: You're not accounting for "long int". And if you do, that's exactly what my answer is.

Comment: @dascandy, ah, forgot about `long int`. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach my $line (@lines_in_the_file) {
    $line =~ s/\blong long\b/SOMETHINGFUNKY/g;
}

foreach my $line (@lines_in_the_file) {
    $line =~ s/\blong\b/int/g;
}

foreach my $line (@lines_in_the_file) {
    $line =~ s/SOMETHINGFUNKY/long long/g;
}
```